# How to turn a function returning [a] into a function returning a Monoid?

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, monoids

I'm playing with Haskell return-type polymorphism using the following function:

```hs
f :: [a] -> [a]
f [] = mempty
f (x:xs) = [x] <> f xs
```

Obviously it does nothing. What I'd like to do is to modify the type so that it takes a list and returns a Monoid container, one of which could be a list. I'm stuck here because `Monoid` takes one type argument. I have no idea what the type could be: `f :: Monoid m => [a] -> ?`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you note, you can't turn an arbitrary `a` into a member of any specific Monoid `m` without a function of type `a -> m` available. But there is no such function that works for *all* Monoid instances - if there were, it'd have to be in the typeclass definition, and you can see it doesn't exist.

Therefore, you have to either specialize `f` to a particular Monoid, as you did here for the `[a]` Monoid; or else accept a transforming function `a -> m` in addition to the `[a]`. That is, your type could become:

```
combine :: Monoid m => (a -> m) -> [a] -> m
```

And if we [ask Hoogle about this type](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=Monoid+m+%3D%3E+%28a+-%3E+m%29+-%3E+%5Ba%5D+-%3E+m&scope=set%3Astackage), we see that your function is already defined (generalizing list to Foldable):

```
foldMap :: (Foldable t, Monoid m) => (a -> m) -> t a -> m
```

You may find it a useful exercise to implement `foldMap`, either for Foldables in general or specialized to lists.

Answer (score 3):

As [@amalloy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/625403/amalloy) said, you need a way to put your list's contents into your "monoid container" - the Monoid class does not define such a thing, so either your list's contents need to already constitute a monoid (in which case, your function is just `mconcat`):

```hs
f :: Monoid m => [m] -> m
f = mconcat
```

or you provide a converter function (in which case you transform the list's contents into your monoid, *then* do mconcat:

```hs
f :: Monoid m => (a -> m) -> [a] -> m
f converter = mconcat . fmap converter
```